# Drawing and animating multiple paths in a Shape in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shapes

I'm trying to implement animation like seen below.

[image]

To start with, based on completed being true or false, to show the appropriate shape ( + or ✓). On tapping of a button, I'd like for the shapes to animate as seen in the image above. As per my understanding:

- If starting with + symbol: (1.) Horizontal stroke opacity goes to zero (2.) The top of the vertical stroke moves from `(midX, minY)` to `(minX, midY)` in anticlockwise fashion to form the left stroke of the ✓ symbol. The bottom of the vertical stroke stays fixed. The right stroke of the ✓ symbol now animates from the bottom of the vertical stroke at `(midX, maxY)` and extending to the top-right to `(maxX, minY)` to complete the shape.
- If starting with ✓ symbol: (1.) The right stroke of ✓ animates backwards from `(maxX, minY)` to the bottom at `(midX, maxY)` where both strokes meet. (2.) The left stroke of ✓ animates back to `(midX, minY)` to form the vertical stroke of the + symbol. (3.) Finally the horizontal stroke of the + symbol animates back to opacity 1.
- The shape animations should reverse on tap of the button. If user were to rapidly tap on the button that toggles the state then the animation duration should be ignored and shapes should just switch between + and ✓ until the user lifts the touch from the button; in which case depending on final state of `completed`, the shape that should show should continue to animate into view.

Edit: Updated code to use different line segment Shapes. However the ✓ symbol's right stroke isn't animating the path drawing. Also the animation doesn't reverse correctly when switching between the shapes.

Any help is appreciated.

```
struct LineSegment1: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        // MARK: ＋ shape's horizontal line
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
        
        return path
    }
}

struct LineSegment2: Shape {
    var endPoint: CGPoint

    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat> {
        get { AnimatablePair(endPoint.x, endPoint.y) }
        set {
            endPoint.x = newValue.first
            endPoint.y = newValue.second
        }
    }

    // MARK: ＋ shape's vertical line & ☑️ shape's left stroke
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let start = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY)
        let end = CGPoint(x: endPoint.x * rect.width, y: endPoint.y * rect.height)
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)
        return path
    }
}

struct LineSegment3: Shape {
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return progress }
        set { progress = newValue }
    }
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 0
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        // MARK: ☑️ shape's, right stroke
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + (rect.maxX * progress), y: rect.minY))
        return path
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var drawProgress: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var completed: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .overlay {
                    ZStack {
                        LineSegment1()
                            .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 4.0)
                            .opacity(completed ? 0 : 1)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        LineSegment2(endPoint: CGPoint(
                            x: completed ? 0.0 : 0.5,
                            y: completed ? 0.5 : 0.0))
                        .stroke(completed ? .yellow : .white, lineWidth: 4.0)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        LineSegment3(progress: drawProgress)
                            .stroke(.yellow, lineWidth: 4.0)
                            .opacity(completed ? 1 : 0)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    }
                }
            
            Button(completed ? "Incomplete" : "Complete") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    drawProgress = 1.0
                    completed.toggle()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an easier way to achieve this animation.

You just need to have 3 lines where the opacity, orientation, length and color are conditional on the state variable, with changes animated. The lengths of the lines should be determined by the bounding frame.

In your instructions you said that segment 2 should have its base at `(midX, maxY)` , but I think it is slightly to the left of center in the original gif and the longer part of the checkmark is at 90 degrees. Anyway, I made it configurable in the version below, so you can try tweaking it.

So here is an attempt to get it working:

```swift
struct PlusOrChecked: View {
    let completed1: Bool
    let completed2: Bool
    let smallTickLineFraction = CGFloat(0.55)

    struct Line: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var path = Path()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
            return path
        }
    }

    private func strokeStyle(height: CGFloat) -> StrokeStyle {
        StrokeStyle(lineWidth: height / 10, lineCap: .round)
    }

    private func xOffsetForCheckmark(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        height * smallTickLineFraction * sin(Double.pi / 4) - (height / 2)
    }

    private func yOffsetForCheckmark(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let y = ((smallTickLineFraction * smallTickLineFraction) / 2).squareRoot()
        return -y * height / 3 // Strictly, should be / 2
    }

    private func lengthForSegment3(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let x = 1 - ((smallTickLineFraction * smallTickLineFraction) / 2).squareRoot()
        return (x * x * 2).squareRoot() * height
    }

    private func segment1(height: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Line()
            .stroke(style: strokeStyle(height: height))
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
            .opacity(completed1 || completed2 ? 0 : 1)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }

    private func segment2(height: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Line()
            .stroke(style: strokeStyle(height: height))
            .frame(height: height * (completed1 || completed2 ? smallTickLineFraction : 1))
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(completed1 || completed2 ? -45 : 0), anchor: .bottom)
            .offset(
                x: completed1 || completed2 ? xOffsetForCheckmark(height: height) : 0,
                y: completed1 || completed2 ? yOffsetForCheckmark(height: height) : 0
            )
            .foregroundColor(completed2 ? .blue : .white)
    }

    private func segment3(height: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Line()
            .stroke(style: strokeStyle(height: height))
            .frame(height: completed1 && completed2 ? lengthForSegment3(height: height) : 0)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(45), anchor: .bottom)
            .offset(
                x: completed1 || completed2 ? xOffsetForCheckmark(height: height) : 0,
                y: completed1 || completed2 ? yOffsetForCheckmark(height: height) : 0
            )
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear
                .overlay {
                    segment1(height: proxy.size.height)
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    segment2(height: proxy.size.height)
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    segment3(height: proxy.size.height)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var completed1 = false
    @State private var completed2 = false
    @State private var timeOfLastTap = Date.now

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            PlusOrChecked(completed1: completed1, completed2: completed2)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .padding(5) // best if >= 5% of frame height
                .background(Color(white: 0.2))

            Button(completed1 ? "Incomplete" : "Complete") {
                let duration = min(0.5, -timeOfLastTap.timeIntervalSinceNow)
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: duration)) {
                    completed1.toggle()
                }
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: duration).delay(max(0, duration - 0.25))) {
                    completed2.toggle()
                }
                timeOfLastTap = Date.now
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: AnimatedLines]

---

*EDIT* Updated to apply a y-offset to the checkmark segments too, so that the checkmark is closer to the center when fully showing. Also made the animation duration dependent on the last tap time, so that rapid tapping causes rapid changes.

*EDIT2* Updated again to use two flags instead of one, so that the second part of the animation can be delayed to run after the first.