# Animate Background

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a background view by placing several blurred shapes over a gradient.

```
struct BlurredBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(colors: [.cyan.opacity(0.7), .purple.opacity(0.8)], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: [.indigo, .teal], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .leading))
                .offset(CGSize(width: -100, height: 100))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(15))
                .blur(radius: 100)
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 300)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .offset(x: -100, y: -150)
                .blur(radius: 100)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
                .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: [.purple, .mint], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .leading))
                .offset(x: 300)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(30))
                .blur(radius: 100)
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 450)
                .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                .offset(x: 120, y: -200)
                .blur(radius: 180)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: blurred background]

Now I want to animate it. The orange circe would slowly change it position by following a path, maybe another circle. One of the rectangles could slide along a curved path, back and forth.

How can I create path-based animations for shapes in SwiftUI? Thanks

Comment: Does this SO post help in animating a shape along a path:                    
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521118/how-to-move-a-view-shape-along-a-custom-path-with-swiftui
Also this post on animating multiple paths:                 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214109/drawing-and-animating-multiple-paths-in-a-shape-in-swiftui